# rails get request not working properly using angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am trying to implement a `search` page using `angular` in my `rails` app. If i go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/search.json` I am successfully getting a `json` response in the browser aswell. so the rails part is working fine.

But in `chrome` if I press search button am getting the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load %30.0.0.0:3000/search. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

and in `firefox` am getting `not found 404 error`.

**app.js**

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.getrooms = function(){
        $http({
            url: "0.0.0.0:3000/search",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function(response){
            $scope.rooms = response;
        });
    };
    });
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
  def search
    @rooms_address = Room.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @rooms_address }
    end
  end
```

**search.html.erb**

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchLocation">

   <button ng-click="getrooms()">Search</button>
```

Could someone tell me what am missing here?

Comment: Your app is running in the same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         url: "0.0.0.0:3000/search"
> ```

Have you tried using `"http://0.0.0.0:3000/search"`, or `"/search"`? The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) do not write the url the way you did. I'd recommend just using `"/search"`.

Edit: Also, have you opened up your console and looked at your network requests? Look at the request header, and make sure it is the correct url. In the future, that should be your first course of action when debugging.

Comment: using "search.json" works.  In header I can see that the url is repeated and was the issue.

Comment: @Abhilash good to hear. Also, if you're using Rails, you can usually set a default response format (typically json) in your routes, allowing you to leave off the .json from the request url.

Comment: will do that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your angular files from `file://`?

Browsers can't make HTTP Requests that way. Host your static files on your server and all should be well.

Comment: Can you double check? I've had people with this exact error multiple times and it was always this problem

Comment: The rails server is running otherwise I wont be able to get the content from the url "http://0.0.0.0:3000/search"

Comment: Yes, the Server is running Rails, but the HTML files, are they running on the server?

Comment: I am not using angular routing here. This is a full rails app. I thought just try angular on the search page. But not working

Comment: That's really odd, if true.